# Localization text is incorrect

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, localization

What could be the key of the problem, i have localization file while I am using it in html the text is correct, but when i use it as a header of popup menu it is shown partly.

```
  <div id="dialog" title=@Resources.Localization.add_skill>
    @Html.Partial("Partial/_SkillPopUp", newSkill)
  </div>
```

this text has to show something like 'add skill', but while it is header shows only 'add'.

Full code of the body is ugly and may be wrong (I`m ablosolutely new to html, will be grateful if anyone could explain html basic mistakes):

```
<body>
   <span class="content_h4">@Resources.Localization.employee_skills</span>
   <br />
   <br />

   @if (Model.EmployeeSkillList.Count > 0)
   {
       <div id="FormContainer">
            @Html.Partial("Partial/_EmployeeSkills", Model)
       </div>
   }
   else
   {
       @Resources.Localization.no_data_found;
   }
   <br />
   <br />

   <div id="dialog" title=@Resources.Localization.add_skill>
       @Html.Partial("Partial/_SkillPopUp", newSkill)
   </div>

   <button id="opener">@Resources.Localization.add_record</button>
</body>
```

Popup :

```
    @model BTGHRM.Models.EmployeeSkillsModel

@{
   var db = new HRMEntities();

   List<BTGHRM.Models.SkillCategories> dropdownCategories = new List<BTGHRM.Models.SkillCategories>();
   foreach (var skillName in db.EmployeeSkillsCategories)
   {
       dropdownCategories.Add(new BTGHRM.Models.SkillCategories() { Value = skillName.Categories, Text = skillName.Categories });
   }

   List<BTGHRM.Models.SkillKnowledgeLevels> dropdownKnowledgeLevels = new    List<BTGHRM.Models.SkillKnowledgeLevels>();
   foreach (var skillKnowledgeLevel in db.EmployeeSkillsKnowledgeLevels)
   {
       dropdownKnowledgeLevels.Add(new BTGHRM.Models.SkillKnowledgeLevels() { Value = skillKnowledgeLevel.KnowledgeLevel, Text = skillKnowledgeLevel.KnowledgeLevel });
   }
}

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <link href="~/Content/themes/custom/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />

     <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#closer").click(function () {
                $("#dialog").dialog("close");
            });
        });
      </script>

</head>


@using (Html.BeginForm("AddSkillToList", "Employee", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.EmployeeId, new { Value = Model.EmployeeId});

    <table>
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.EmployeeId)
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Category)</td>
            <td>
                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Category, dropdownCategories.Select(item => new SelectListItem {Value = item.Value, Text = item.Text}), new { style = "width:250px" })
            </td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name)</td>
            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name,  new { style = "width:246px", htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })</td>
            <td>@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.KnowledgeLevel)</td>
            <td>
                @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.KnowledgeLevel, dropdownKnowledgeLevels.Select(item => new SelectListItem { Value = item.Value, Text = item.Text }), new { style = "width:250px" })
            </td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.AdditionalInfo)</td>
            <td>@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.AdditionalInfo, new { style = "width:246px", htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })</td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>

    </table>

    <input style="width:78px" type="submit" value=@Resources.Localization.save />

}

<button id="closer">@Resources.Localization.back</button>
```

Comment: I suspect word wrapping. Try adding this style to the popup: `style="white-space:nowrap"`

Comment: @Ryan Peters, I had to do it like that, or I missunderstood?
` <div id="dialog" title=@Resources.Localization.add_skill style="white-space:nowrap">

        @Html.Partial("Partial/_SkillPopUp", newSkill)
    </div>`
But this did not help.

Comment: Can you provide more context like the containing markup (the element that wraps the <div>)? And/or try the nowrap style in the container element not the <div> itself.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot recreate the issue or am not fully understanding the problem.

Comment: @Ryan Peters title of `@Html.Partial("Partial/_SkillPopUp", newSkill)` this popup is 'add', but it has to be 'add skill', in localization file `@Resources.Localization.add_skill` text is 'add skill', but word skill is just ignored while it is header of popup

Comment: Please post the markup in Partial/_SkillPopUp

Comment: Try and apply the style `style="white-space:nowrap"` to the html element within the Popup that is displaying "Add Skill". I believe it is one of the `<td>` tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I forgot to put double quotes in title, it has to look like :

```
 <div id="dialog" title="@Resources.Localization.add_skill">
```